# как рисовать на canvas квадратами так чтобы они не налазили друг на друга

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

подскажите как реализовать рисование квадратами так чтобы когда ведешь мышью квадоаты не накладывались друг на друга (к примеру размер канваса 512 на 512, a размер одного рисовального пикселя равен 8 на 8)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пример на картинке
помогите с проблемой буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Какие квадраты "налазиют" друг на друга?

Answer (score 1):

Кажется так:

```js
let clamp = (e, n) => [Math.floor(e.layerX/n)*n, Math.floor(e.layerY/n)*n];
let draw, ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
addEventListener('mousedown', () => draw = true);
addEventListener('mouseup', () => draw = false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => draw && ctx.fillRect(...clamp(e, 8), 8, 8));
```

```css
canvas {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #0003
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=512 height=176></canvas>
```

Comment: спасибо большое работает, но может вы знаете  как в этот код реализовать алгоритма Брезенхэма. дабы при быстром рисовании не было пробелов

Comment: @ПашаХодор в целом можно, но уже надо собирать точки и рисовать линии а не просто пиксели закрашивать

Comment: ctx.lineTo(e.layerX, e.layerY);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(e.layerX, e.layerY, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(e.layerX, e.layerY)

Comment: для круга использовал этот код. для квадрата не выходит